# is there documentation about how to move an EE2 web site?

Tags: ee2

I am about to change hosting, is there documentation about how to move an EE2 web site from one host to another?

Comment: StackExchange is a wonder resource for getting help and tips from other developers, but I would strongly suggest doing a little research on google, the ExpressionEngine Docs pages, and even here on the EE StackExchange before posting questions such as these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a google search for "expressionengine moving a site" the first link is the [ExpressionEngine Documentation for doing so.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html)